# Sitecore 9.0 - Looking to implement Azure AD B2C

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

Thank you for reading my question.

I'am trying to implement Azure AD B2C in Sitecore 9.0.2 version that being said i have used a sample code from [Git Hub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi) which implemented ADB2C using ASP.NET MVC. I created a feature project in Sitecore added all the files needed,built the solution and deployed it to Sitecore web root, resolved dll conflicts but still seeing one issue:

Sitecore have an older version of "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" dll with class "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler" which is no longer available in Version=5.2.1.0

Any help/guidance here to resolve this issue or is there any sample implementation available in Sitecore with Azure AD B2C.

Note: i'am not looking for Federated Authentication (Azure Active Directory) Azure AD

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK6uf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create Azure AD B2C :

1. Login to Portal.azure.com and create a New Tenant (working directory
   with subscription)
2. Link your Subscription
3. Create/Register an Application (Client)
4. Create Client Secret, User Flows, Custom policies [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview)
5. Create an MVC application which can generate Azure Login Url [reference](https://devandme.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/authenticating-a-sitecore-external-user-as-a-customer-via-azure-b2c-part-1/#more-103)
6. Deploy your code to sitecore root & browse the site.

Open Issues : Users need to be created in Sitecore manually even after having Virtual User creation in place.